# Flutter signedapk build error in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, signed-apk

Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease
Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code 254
Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code 254

> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands to clear all your project and rebuild

```
flutter create .
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: i`m using android studio

Comment: You can use this commands in terminal

Comment: ok Sir i`ll try and tell you in a while.

Comment: > Task :path_provider_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I`ll get this error after tried flutter clean and pub get commands

Comment: This error was mapped in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93389 and the fix was already merged into master.
You can try to update path_provider version to the latest version and try to clean the project and build again.

Comment: If the problem persists you should follow the next path_provider update, it would fix this error.